# chainType in custom spec

Tags: configuration

I would like to know what are the possible values for

`"chainType": "Live"` in the custom spec file, and what is the meaning of each one of them.

Also how to use `Custom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible values can be seen [here](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/sc_service/enum.ChainType.html#variants). They are: Development, Local, Live and Custom.

As to the meaning of each, as far as I know, there isn't much difference from local and dev. Live is a bit different, as there are some default configurations which change if that's your chain type. For example, if your chain is set to Live, by default it will have the `--no-private-ipv4` parameter set.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of all the exact changes and the documentation is very poor in that regard. My recommendation (and what I've been doing) as of now is to dig through the substrate source code.

Comment: Thx ed. what do they mean by Custom(String) ?

Comment: That is for when you define a new type which is neither of the predefined ones. So you can have it called whatever you want.

Comment: but when i use "chainType": "whateverIwant" it doesn't work I get an error.

Comment: Just tested it and you need to pass it in as `"chainType": { "Custom": "Whatever you want" }`